# How do you package the JDBC jar in an extension?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, plugins, bluej

I'm working on a plugin for the BlueJ IDE.  These plugins are packaged as simple JAR files that sit in the BlueJ project.  The plugin involves submitting (sometimes fetching) data to a MySQL server.  I have it operating using the JDBC connector (as a JAR) from my path.  I need the plugin to be an easy install for students where they simply drop it into a folder.  Is there a way to keep the JDBC piece with my extension and not have to place it separately on the student's machine?

I have read a little about ClassLoaders from here http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch21-ClassLoaders_and_J2EE.htm.  But I haven't gleaned a nice way to do what I'm asking. I am using Eclipse, by the way.

This question gets very close to what I want at the very end when the manifest is mentioned:
[Deployment Concepts: Packaging JAR Dependencies, When & Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473260/deployment-concepts-packaging-jar-dependencies-when-why)

My only problem now is that I need to know how to edit the manifest file in such a way to point my extension at its own directory to find the JDBC connector.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get my problem solved by editing the manifest file of my extension.  When building, I followed directions from here

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-35.htm

After an initial packaging, I edited the generated file to include a line for my JDBC JAR.  The steps for this were taken from this site:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to unzip the JDBC connector and package it together with your code in one big jar file. If you don't have any package naming conflicts, everything should work fine.

Comment: This is an interesting solution that I haven't considered.  Because the line that basically connects to the jar is
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Then you are suggesting I ignore this line, and instead, import it all as a package then instantiate things like "normal"?  I'm just a little blown away it could be so easy.  I'll try this soon when I get onto my development machine then update with how it went.  Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to be a viable solution.  When I attempt to move the packages within the JAR, I get an ungodly number of error messages about improper permissions and dependencies and etc.  Thanks for the tip, but I don't think this solution will work for me.

Comment: I got it to work by editing the manifest file.  Very easy.  Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: **WARNING** - doing that may violate the license of the JDBC driver.  The MySQL Connector/J libraries are GPL version 2.

Comment: Hey Stephen,
Thanks for pointing that out.  It didn't even occur to me.  Good thing it didn't work out anyways!